# Cast from pointer to integer of different size

Tags: c, casting

The STRAIGHTFORWARD code gives me gcc warning `"cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]"`.
Does that mean the STRAIGTHFORWARD cast is illegal C?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *thr(void *Arg)
{
#if  STRAIGHTFORWARD
    printf("i=%d\n", (int)Arg);
#else
    printf("i=%d\n", (int)(intptr_t)Arg);
#endif
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t tids[4];
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof tids / sizeof tids[0]; i++){
#if  STRAIGHTFORWARD
        pthread_create(tids+i, 0, thr, (void*)i);
#else
        pthread_create(tids+i, 0, thr, (void*)(intptr_t)i);
#endif

    }

    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Does that mean the STRAIGTHFORWARD cast is illegal C?*

It is highly implementation defined, if not illegal. Compiler is trying to warn you of the potential pitfall.

Quoting `C11`, §6.3.2.3

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

That is why `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are there.

That said, `(int)(intptr_t)Arg` also defeats the purpose, there's no guarantee of size compatibility between `int` and `intptr_t`, so the cast is error prone as much as the one without `intptr_t`.

Comment: The intptr_t is there because I put it there because it silences the warning :D Thanks.

Comment: suggest to explicitly add that OPs construct `(int)(intptr_t)Arg)` only silences compiler warnings, but leads to a similar problem if `int` is really smaller than `void *`

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah, probably better, will add.

Comment: @PSkocik and in your special case, you *know* this pointer only holds an `int`, so silencing the warning is fine. I'd still suggest to pass a pointer to something to your threads, though

Comment: @FelixPalmen "(int)(intptr_t)Arg) only silences compiler warnings, but leads to a similar problem if int is really smaller than void *" What problem do you mean?

Comment: If int is smaller than void*, than int is smaller than intptr_t, which means int to intptr_t is an upcast, so everything should be fine, no?

Comment: @PSkocik as I said, in your special case where you know what you "hid" in the pointer, it is fine. Still it just silences the warning, and if the `void *` would indeed hold a pointer, you'd have hidden a bug.

Comment: @PSkocik I din't mean _in your code_, i meant _in the spec_ :)